# Parse Database Authorization - Security For User Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, parse-platform

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4 web application where i use Parse as database in the back-end (https://www.parse.com/) and C# as programming language.

I use ParseUser class to log in registered users (https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#users-login) like this:

```
ParseUser.LogInAsync("my_username", "my_password");
```

Then i have created a custom authorization attribute and i apply it in some controllers and action methods of my project.

```
public class AuthorizeParseUserAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (ParseUser.CurrentUser != null && ParseUser.CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is Parse's documentation for CurrentUser property https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#users-current

**So, I have the following problem:** I successfully log in using my credentials. After log in, i enter the main page of my application (the AuthorizeParseUserAttribute has been applied to the corresponding action method). Then i send the url of this main page to another person, in another computer and the user (which is not even a registered user) can see the main page of my application and is logged in with my credentials!!! Parse's documentation for security for user objects is the following https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#users-security

Can you please propose any solution to solve this very serious problem? Thank you.

Comment: your attribute just returns false, should you not be redirecting the user to either a not authorised http response, or to the login page?   at moment  your controller just goes, yep that's false, carry on

Comment: @davethecoder When this attribute returns false then the user is redirected to the login page automatically, if this is specified in the web.config. The problem is that ParseUser.CurrentUser.IsAuthenticated returns true when a non-authenticated user from every client when i do not log out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Parse SDK for .NET assumes you are building an app that is running on one device per user - it's not designed to integrate with ASP.NET.

From [the docs](https://www.parse.com/docs/dotnet_guide#users):

> Whenever you use any signup or login methods, the user is cached on disk.

ParseUser.CurrentUser is a static method that returns the cached user from the latest call to a signup or login method. This is why in your code, after one user logs in, everybody else that makes a request is also logged in as that user!

I am attempting to integrate Parse with an ASP.NET MVC site I'm currently developing. My plan to work around this limitation is to set the authentication cookie after logging in with Parse, then log out the user (their authentication cookie will still be set though).

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    ParseUser user;

    try
    {
        user = await ParseUser.LogInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);
    }
    catch (ParseException e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }

    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.Username, model.RememberMe);
    ParseUser.LogOut();

    return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
}
```

The Register method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Attempt to register the user
        try
        {
            var user = new ParseUser
            {
                Username = model.UserName,
                Password = model.Password,
            };

            await user.SignUpAsync();

            FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.UserName, false);
            ParseUser.LogOut();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", e.Message);
        }
    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    return View(model);
}
```