# Parse authorization in mvc5 - login issues

Tags: parse-platform, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm writing an app that's supposed to run with MVC5 and using [parse](http://parse.com) as a backend.
I'm using the new Identity feature of the MVC5 to login an user. I also tried to use this [solution](https://github.com/corrego/Parse.AspNet.Identity) but I couldn't make it work.

What is happening is that when I login with the user A and then login with the user B in a different session (a incognito windows or a new browser) whenever I try to insert something related with a ParseUser object using the first user that was logged in I get an exception: UserCannotBeAlteredWithoutSessionError.

I'm not sure if I'm doing the implementation in a wrong way, or if it is a limitation of the Parse (I think it was designed to run using one user per device).
If you have a workaround for this situation please help me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a good answer which may help: [Parse Database Authorization - Security For User Objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596275).
So, it's a kind of Parse SDK limitation, when you can work with only one user per device (as ParseUser is cached locally). The only workaround that I can see is to perform SignOut/Login explicitly, when you need to do something from other user's context. There is no way to have two users work simultaneously from the same device.