# Retrieving T from Task<T>

Tags: c#, asynchronous, parse-platform, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await

I'm working on ASP.NET MVC5 app based around Parse.com framework.

Since i can't use Parse login method i had to use method posted here to work around its limitations: [Parse.com multiple users issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20596275/parse-database-authorization-security-for-user-objects/21662318#21662318)

Here is my login method(just minor changes):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(AccountModel model) //no returnUrl string
{
    ParseUser user;

    try
    {
        user = await ParseUser.LogInAsync(model.UserName, model.Password);//login parse user
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
        return View(model);
    }
   //making setAuthCookie get parse object id instead of username
    FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user.ObjectId, model.RememberMe);
    ParseUser.LogOut(); //log out parse user

    return RedirectToAction("index", "home"); //Redirect to Action
}
```

So basically i (parse)login user, set AuthCookie to it's object id and then (parse)logoff user. That way i can have multiple users logged in.Out of SetAuthCookie i can get users id now.

However i'd like to display some extra user data(like user adress, Type, Name, LastName) that is on parse.com cloud. So i figured i will just write a method that will get this data by using currently authenticated userID, fill my AccountModel class object with data and then pass it to views. This is a loose idea of how it'd look like(i know syntax is probably wrong, i don't have access to my Visual studio right now):

UserData model:

```
public async Task<AccountModel> GetUserData()
{
    AccountModel userData = new AccountModel();
    ParseObject user;

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseObject.GetQuery("_User");
    try
    {
       //i can't remember how to get authenticated user identity
        user = await query.GetAsync(AuthenticatedUser.Identity());
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       //code to handle exception
    }

    userData.Name = user.Get<string>("Name");
    userData.Lastname = user.Get<string>("Lastname");
    userData.Adress = user.Get<string>("Adress");

   return userData; //it will probably throw an error
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    UserData model = new UserData();
    return View(model.GetUserData());
}
```

**So now it will probably throw an error(can't return T from Task< T >) and i have no idea how to fix this, so i can get currently logged in user data.**

I have nav bar on my site where user name and last name is displayed, so i have to somehow get currently logged in user data every time page is displayed. Is there any work around/easier way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You fix this by making your Action asynchronous as well:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    UserData model = new UserData();
    return View(await model.GetUserData());
}
```

Async goes "all the way". This means that once you have an asynchronous method that needs to be awaited, it will usually cause most (if not all) of your stack-trace to be asynchronous as well.

**Side note:**

Once should stick to .NET conventions and mark async methods with the `XXXAsync` postfix, so your method should actually be named `GetUserDataAsync`.